# Left joining multiple tables using the same table alias (only one will load based on condition)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've got a list of tables that we use in our database for products stored in its own database.  I set up an array of "tables" using this code.

```
$TABLES_QUERY = $db1q->query("SELECT t.table FROM Product_Tables as t WHERE t.visibility = 1 ORDER BY t.sort_order ASC") or die ('Unable to execute query. '. mysqli_error($db1q));
    if ($TABLES_QUERY->num_rows > 0) { 
    while ($TABLES = $TABLES_QUERY->fetch_assoc()) {
        $query_tables_array[] = $TABLES['table'];
    }
    }
```

What I am trying to do in our inventory system is pull data from the correct table without having to write out every single table and each table have a unique table alias.  That would mean everytime a new product table is created, the code would have to be updated.  I would much rather just add that table into the tables database, and the code still works....

Below is the code I was attempting to use...

```
if (!empty($query_tables_array)) {
    foreach ($query_tables_array as $val) { 
        $SKU_QUERY .= " LEFT JOIN ". $val ." as ptbl ON
    (s.product_table='". $val ."' and ptbl.id = s.part_number_id)";
    }
    }
```

There are conditions applied to the table so only one should be called, but its throwing the error

> Not unique table/alias: 'ptbl'

Is there a proper way of doing this where it will work?

I'm using ptbl in the SELECT query to get data from the LEFT JOIN'D table so I'd prefer to be able to do this similarly to how I am trying to if there is a way.

This is probably quite confusing, so please let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: Why would a new product table be created? This kind of problem can be indicative of poor schema design

Comment: I agree with the previous comment. However the problem is that $query_tables_array has multiple items and you can use an alias only once in the same query. I would change this to

  `if (!empty($query_tables_array)) {
      foreach ($query_tables_array as $val) { 
          $SKU_QUERY .= " LEFT JOIN ". $val ." ON
      (s.product_table='". $val ."' and $val.id = s.part_number_id)";
      }
      }`

Comment: @husseinNegm - I was able to use a variation of your recommendation.  Can you add as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I only use that inside my development area and in areas not accessible to public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that $query_tables_array has multiple items and you can use an alias only once in the same query. I would change this to

```
if (!empty($query_tables_array)) 
  { foreach ($query_tables_array as $val) 
    { $SKU_QUERY .= " LEFT JOIN ". $val ." 
      ON (s.product_table='". $val ."' and $val.id = s.part_number_id)"; 
    } 
  }
```